# sql find most recent record

Tags: sql

I have the following query which gets a tally of records with the given criteria.  The following shows the two records in the table and the results of the query.  What I want is to just get the most recent occurrence based on the `EntryDate` column.

```
0 A 2012-08-09 00:00:00.000 N0206527 N0168639 NULL 09 420202 LTD False  
0 A 2012-08-08 00:00:00.000 N0206527 N0168639 NULL 09 420202 LTD False

DCMNumber CustomerDivision CustomerSerial Product PriorNonDenied    
N0064819  09               420202     LTD     2


SET @firstDayOfCurrentMonth = DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(M,0,GETDATE()),0)
SELECT  DCMNumber, CustomerDivision, CustomerSerial, Product, COUNT(*) AS PriorNonDenied
                             FROM   cauAssignedClaim 
                             WHERE  RecordType = 'A' AND  
                                   EscFromSTD = '0' AND  
                                   ([Status] <> 'DE' OR  
                                    [Status] IS NULL) AND  
                                   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), EntryDate, 110) BETWEEN  
                                       CASE WHEN Product = 'LTD' THEN   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @firstDayOfCurrentMonth, 110)    
                                       ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(Day, -7, GETDATE()-1), 110)  
                                       END  
                                       AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 110) 
                             GROUP BY [Status],  
                                      DCMNumber,  
                                      CustomerDivision,  
                                      CustomerSerial,  
                                      Product
```

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 4):

I think you want something like this

```
SELECT a.EntryDate, a.DCMNumber, CustomerDivision, CustomerSerial, Product, WhateverElse, etc
FROM cauAssignedClaim b INNER JOIN

(SELECT MAX(DCMNumber) DCMNumber, MAX(EntryDate) EntryDate
FROM cauAssignedClaim
GROUP BY DCMNumber) a

ON ( a.DCMNumber = b.DCMNumber AND a.EntryDate = b.EntryDate )
```

This will give you a list of all unique DCMNumbers and their latest date.  Then you can JOIN that with all the rest of the data that you need.   The end result will return each DCMNumber with the latest info.

If that's not what you're looking for, add more details, so we can better understand what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY EntryDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

MSSQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ORDER BY EntryDate DESC
```

Comment: Just to note, this is valid for MySQL only.  `LIMIT` is not standard SQL.

Comment: Using TOP 1 only returns on row.  I have several records where the DCMNumber is assigned different claim numbers.  What I am trying to get is the latest DCMNumber for all claims.  So in the end I will have a list of the latest claims assigned to a DCMNumber.  The reason for this is that I don't want to include more than one record  in cases where the same claim number has been assigned more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select Top 1 col1 From Table Order by MyDate DESC
```

Comment: With TOP 1 I only get back one record.  In the table I have several claims assigned to a particular DCMNumber.  What I need is to get the last instance of each claim for a particular DCMNUmber.