# Finding the most recent record in a joined query

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I have a MySQL relational database which stores customers in one table, and then another table which stores various contacts/conversations/engagements with them. See the examplar schema below:

*Customers*
customerId
forename
surname

*Contacts*
contactId
customerId
correspondenceDescription
contactDate

I need to be able to query the database and be able to access the date (contactDate) of the most recent time we have been in touch with them. I've seen a few other questions on here, but I dont seem to be able to find one which suits my needs.

Can anyone help? Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934960/sql-find-most-recent-record

Comment: and the code you tried was? and the problem wit that code is?

Comment: Brilliant, just what I needed. I was using left join, just couldn't figure out a way to get the most recent contact date! Thansks @halfer

Comment: @halfer Might want to turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Good idea @BellevueBob. OP, pleased it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here's a starting point. You need to get your contacts grouped by customer ID, so I'd start with this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(contactDate), customerId
FROM
    Contacts
GROUP BY
    customerId
```

From there, you can `LEFT JOIN` to your customers table, and you'll be able to see the last contact date against each customer. If you are sure that each customer has at least one contact, you can swap this for `INNER JOIN`, which should speed things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try these query:

To retrieve the most recent contactDate of all customer (when you display all customer as a list):

```
SELECT Customers.*, max(Contacts.contactDate) as Most_Recent
from Customers left join Contacts
ON Customers.customerId = Contacts.customerId
GROUP BY Customers.customerId
ORDER BY Most_Recent desc
```

To retrieve the most recent contactDate of a customer (change id 1 with your customer's id):

```
SELECT Customers.*, Contacts.contactDate as Most_Recent
from Customers left join Contacts
ON Customers.customerId = Contacts.customerId
where Customers.customerId = 1
ORDER BY Most_Recent desc
```

Comment: I don't remember in MySQL, but in SQL standard, all columns must be listed in the group clause.  MySQL does some weird things with this though if I recall.

Comment: This query is illegal in standard SQL but it is legal in MySQL 
See this topic: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

I would generally encourage people to name columns explicity, and not to use explicit join syntax - some versions of MySQL do silly things.  Aggregates are often slower than doing a order with a limit, so I'd do:

```
    select customerId, forename, surname, contactId, correspondenceDescription, contactDate
        from customer, contacts
        where customer.customerId = contacts.customerId
        and customer.customerId = ?
        order by contactDate desc
        limit 0,1
```